# Python: random.seed is different but randint generate same number

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am facing a very unique issue.

```
random.seed(123)

rg = PhoneMetadata.metadata_for_region(random.choice(('US', 'FR', 'IN', 'GB')))
pl = rg.mobile.possible_length
cc = rg.country_code

print(''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(pl[0])))
--3982597919

random.seed(345)

rg = PhoneMetadata.metadata_for_region(random.choice(('US', 'FR', 'IN', 'GB')))
pl = rg.mobile.possible_length
cc = rg.country_code

print(''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(pl[0])))
--3982597919
```

**I am giving different seeds number but the output its giving me the same number. Its not happening every time but i am facing this issue randomly.**

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What about `random.getstate()`? Could it be that `PhoneMetatdata` sets the seed?

Comment: No  this is not the case here.

Comment: Unable to duplicate on Python 2.7 (assuming that `PhoneMetadata` is not actually relevant).  What *exact* version are you seeing this with?

Answer (score 0):

> Any help would be really appreciated.

Since you already ruled out `PhoneMetadata`, one debugging help might be to save the random-state each invocation, and to examine it if things go wrong. To save:

```
pickle.dump(random.getstate(), open(tempfile.mktemp(), "w"))
```

To restore, have a look at the temp directory, sort by date, and restore the latest via, say

```
random.setstate(pickle.load(open("/tmp/tmpQMWOE4")))
```

and then see if you can reproduce the behavior with this state.